# Skip null value to next worksheet and paste to another workbook with sama name sheet

Tags: excel, vba

1. this is **Workbook A**, and have 7 sheets, how i looping  column **G** when **G** has value `1` and paste it in another workbook and automatically create sheet name like **Workbook A**, like a looping paste
2. while looping and found sheet that not have value `1` in **column G**, how can I skip that sheets and start looping to the next sheet, because when sheet not have value `1` in **column G**, looping will automatically **stop**, how can I fix that?

.

```
 Sub historical()
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet, sheetIndex As Integer
    Dim baris As Long, pasterowIndex As Long
    sheetIndex = 8
    pasterowIndex = 2
    For Each currentSheet In Worksheets
        For baris = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
            If Cells(baris, 7).Value = "1" Then
                Rows(baris).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets(sheetIndex).Select
                Rows(pasterowIndex).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                pasterowIndex = pasterowIndex + 1
                currentSheet.Select
            End If
        Next baris
        pasterowIndex = 2
        sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1
    Next currentSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you should take a step back and explain what your code aims to do. Room for improvement here on multiple levels (which is fine). If you can clearly explain what you need to do, we can help clean your code up

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @urdearboy sorry my bad, this is like my first post...
i just want to copy row where G column has a value "1".. in G column only have two value ("0","1")... And paste it to another workbook automatically

Comment: @FaisalAbraham that wasn’t meant to be a put down! Nothing wrong with your code - it’s far better than most first posts :)

Comment: I don't see another workbook in your code. Shouldn't this code be housed in your workbook that will store all of the imported data? My approach would be `1:` Bring up file dialogue to select workbook to import. `2:` Cycle through sheets. Filter **Column G** by **1** `3:` Copy/paste visible cells.

Comment: @urdearboy but my code doesn't paste (row) automatically to another sheet, it just got an error because doesn't have place to paste it, i dont want to create sheet manualy because to many file like this to proses..
and it while it looping and found one of the sheet doesn't have "1" in it will stop looping..

maybe the proses i want like this
wb A->check and copy row  value in sheet(AA)->wb B->automatically create sheet(AA) and paste from wb A sheetAA -> back to wb A->check and copy row  value in sheet(AB)->wb B->automatically create sheet(AB) and paste from wb A sheetAB-> to end sheet

Comment: @urdearboy because i dont know ho to do it
i add 2 workbook but got an error